# Pandas .DataFrame() puts column names and index into brackets

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a dataframe manually, so I can add values to it in a second step.
I use two imported csvs, which only exist of 1 column with values.

```
tags = pd.read_csv('top1000_tags.csv')
print(tags)
```

[image]
[image]

The command I used to create the DF:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=tracks, columns=tags)
```

But for some reason the method puts every value into brackets and adds a comma after the name:

[image]

I also tried adding values to the dataframe with `data=np.zeros((10000,1000))` which also doesn't work.

What might be the reason for this behavior?

Comment: what are `tracks` and `tags`? You likely have a nested structure, unnest it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing a 2D structure as index/columns, thus the MultiIndex (with one level)

Use Series instead:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=tracks['Track_Id'], columns=tags['tag'])
```

Output:

```
tag   rock  pop alternative
track                      
A      NaN  NaN         NaN
B      NaN  NaN         NaN
C      NaN  NaN         NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems what you want to do is `df = pd.DataFrame(data=tags, index=tracks.values.flatten())`